# How to remove a component from backdrop

Tags: angular

I have a custom angular component, which consists of an input field and an attached cdk overlay. The overlay opens when anything is entered in the input. Everything works fine in general. The grey backdrop is wanted, but I require the input to be not part of the overlay backdrop. A click into the input should not drop back, neither it should have the grey color from the backdrop.

I have trouble to figure out how to achieve this. Please help.

Edit:
Very simplyfied stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dqbexu

Comment: please post your the code  here

Comment: Added a stackblitz